# Long double overflows but value smaller than maximum representable value

Tags: c++, infinity, long-double

I'm trying to compute a series using C++.
The series is:
[image: series]  (for those wondering)

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath> // exp 
#include <iomanip> //setprecision, setw 
#include <limits> //numeric_limits (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

long double SminOneCenter(long double gamma)
{
    using std::endl; using std::cout;
    long double result=0.0l;
    for (long double k = 1; k < 1000 ; k++)
    {   
            if(isinf(pow(1.0l+pow(gamma,k),6.0l/4.0l)))
            {   
                    cout << "infinity for reached for gamma equals:   " << gamma <<  "value of k:  " << k ; 
                    cout << "maximum allowed:   " <<  std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()<< endl;
                    break;
            }   

                    // CAS PAIR: -1^n = 1
                    if ((int)k%2 == 0)
                    {   
                            result += pow(4.0l*pow(gamma,k),3.0l/4.0l) /(pow(1+pow(gamma,k)),6.0l/4.0l);
                    }   
                    // CAS IMPAIR:-1^n = -1
                    else if ((int)k%2!=0)
                    {   
                            result -= pow(4.0l*pow(gamma,k),3.0l/4.0l) /(pow(1+pow(gamma,k)),6.0l/4.0l);

                            //if (!isinf(pow(k,2.0l)*zeta/2.0l))
                    }   
                    //              cout << result << endl;
    }    


    return 1.0l + 2.0l*result;
}
```

Output will be, for instance with `gamma = 1.7` :
 *infinity reached for gamma equals:   `1.7` value of `k`:  `892`*

The maximum value a `long double` can represent, as  provided by the STL `numeric_limits`, is: `1.18973e+4932`.

However `(1+1.7^892)= 2.19.... × 10^308` which is way lower than `10^4932`, so it shouldn't be considered as infinity.

Provided my code is not wrong (but it very well might be), could anyone tell me why the discussed code evals to infinity when it should not?

Comment: To start with: You do know that floating point arithmetic on computers will leads to compounded rounding errors? (See e.g. [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)) Secondly, have you tried stepping through your code, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, i knew floating point math isn't safe from errors, but that wasn't the issue, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `powl` rather than `pow` if you want to supply `long double` arguments.

Currently you are hitting the `numeric_limits<double>::max()` in your `pow` calls.

As an alternative, consider using `std::pow` which has appropriate overloads.

Reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow

Comment: Isn't pow supposed to be overloaded for long double? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Comment: No. See the link.

Comment: Your link is for `<math.h>`.  The OP is using `<cmath>` which is overloaded: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Comment: Well, it can't be much else. It's either that sizeof(long double) is sizeof(double) or the compiler is picking up `pow`. But let's keep an eye on it: please retain the downvote if you think I'm incorrect as it helps the peer review process. I will delete the answer if it's shown to be incorrect.

Comment: @NathanOliver But what magic is allowing that `pow` to be called unqualified without `using namespace std;`? (Unless that was omitted in OP's code, that is.) Something here doesn't quite make sense...

Comment: @cdhowie Dang and blast.  I thought I saw a `using namespace std;`.  They must also be using the `isinf` from `<math.h>` as well

Comment: I have a special key to type `std::` on my DasKeyboard. I *never* use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @cdhowie `<cmath>` must put its names into `::std`, but it *may* also put them into `::`. `<math.h>` must put its names into `::`, but it *may* also put them into `::std`.

Comment: Damnit. So isinf also exist outside namespace std? I'll try to add std:: everywhere i use math function and see if it was it. Strange thing is i have almost the same function for another series and it's working perfectly without using std::pow in lieu of pow. (And this second series uses fractional exponent as well)

Comment: Okay, seems it was it. Calling std::pow and std::isinf doesn't trigger the if unless the long double is actually overflowing. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: As a final point, always add the smaller floating point terms first in a series.

Comment: Shouldn't you have got a compiler warning about loss of precision when you passed a long double to a ::pow that took a double? Unless, of course, your warning level is not set high enough.